# Not able to access app.config in class library with window service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have folder structure as below

```
ConsoleApp
   app.config
WindowService
   service
   app.config
DataLayer
```

I need to get app.config data such as connection string in DataLayer.I am not able to get. It throws null reference. In consoleApp and WindowService project, its is working.

please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Edit : I am not able to get it in window service project as well.

Comment: Can you share related code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default .NET application uses it's own app.config file when you access it via ConfigurationManager. In order to open another project's configuration you have to load it manually.

The following code snippet opens an external app.config located under the data layer project and accesses the ConnectionStrings section of that file:

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = @"path\to\datalayer\app.config" };
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myDBConn"];
```